# MySQL: Eliminate rows from a SUM function when a 'flag' column has value of 1

Tags: mysql

In the view below:

```
CREATE VIEW msr_joined_view AS 
SELECT table1.id AS msr_id, table1.msr_number, table1.overview, 
SUM(table2.quantity * table2.unit_price) AS grand_total 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.msr_id 
GROUP BY table1.msr_number;
```

I need `SUM(table2.quantity * table2.unit_price)` to ignore any rows where the column `table2.deleted_record` is equal to 1, so that if I have the following data in my table:

```
table2
------
  msr_id(FK)  quantity    unit_price     deleted_record
  ----------  --------    ----------     --------------
     3          3             1.00          0
     3          10            9.99          1
     3          1             5.00          0
```

My `grand_total` for that group should only be 6.00.

I'm not handy with SQL IF or CASE statements. Is that the way to go, or is there a better way?

Comment: Do you need to see the row you want to exclude? Why not just add a Where clause to filter it out before the aggregation?

Comment: Any row with `deleted_record = 1` does not need to be taken into account at all when totaling the record groups. The view does not need to be aware of them. I'm unsure where to put the WHERE clause in my CREATE statement, but that would likely get me what I need.

Comment: If you look for a basic guide to SQL query syntax, you will know where to put the `where` clause: between the source tables (`from` and `join`) clauses and the `group by`. (Bonus: the optional `having` clause is like `where` but applied _after_ grouping, so it can filter on aggregates.)

Comment: Add it before the group by and after the join

Comment: Where table2.Deleted_record = 0

Comment: Apologies if that sounded like a rookie question. For some reason, when I added `WHERE table2.deleted_record = 0` to my CREATE statement, my results made no sense; however, when I changed it to `WHERE table2.deleted_record != 1`, I got back the results I was expecting. Wouldn't those two clauses be evaluated the same way if I have nothing but 0's and 1's in the column?

Comment: I would think they would be evaluated the same. I use SQL Server. I'm not too familiar with MYSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a filter. You can do this by adding a where clause

```
CREATE VIEW msr_joined_view AS 
SELECT table1.id AS msr_id, table1.msr_number, table1.overview, 
SUM(table2.quantity * table2.unit_price) AS grand_total 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.msr_id
WHERE table2.Deleted_record != 1
GROUP BY table1.msr_number;
```

As reference for you and others, and as was pointed out in the comments, the having clause is useful too.

For instance, let's say you wanted to filter your aggregated results where the the grand total needs to be > 10. You could do that like this...

```
CREATE VIEW msr_joined_view AS 
SELECT table1.id AS msr_id, table1.msr_number, table1.overview, 
SUM(table2.quantity * table2.unit_price) AS grand_total 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.msr_id
WHERE table2.Deleted_record != 1
GROUP BY table1.msr_number;
HAVING grand_total > 10
```

Comment: See my comment above. For some bizarre reason, that didn't work, but changing it to `WHERE table2.deleted_record !=1` did.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is evaluated differently but I updated the answer so others can have a valid answer.

Comment: What is the data type? Is it an INT or a Bit? Or a string lol

Comment: tinyint(1) NOT NULL

Comment: I wonder if < 1 would work. If you try it might help me understand what's happening. Don't worry about it if you have other stuff to do.